# Using process.env when react server side rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, server-side-rendering

I have a react app that works pretty well client-side and am now attempting to have it work server-side.

I am using it with the create-react-app boilerplate:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

I am running into an issue where I store some environment variables in .env, however on the server I cannot access these variables.

So a line such as `axios.get(process.env.API_URL + 'something')` will through a 404 because `process.env.API_URL` is `undefined`.

It is my understanding that .env is the file I should be using for stuff like this.  Am I incorrect?  Should I be using another method to store common environment variables?  Or is there some way to get the node server to recognize these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (should) serve the production build.

When you make `npm run build` webpack takes the entries on your `.env` file and replaces them on the build with the corresponding values.

For server-side rendering you'll have to define the environment variables in your node server, either as system environment variables or on a `.env` read by your back-end server (which could be the one webpack-dev-server is using).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Create React App docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), in order to expose environment variables to React both in static and SSR apps, the variable names must be prefixed with `REACT_APP_`. This prevents sensitive and/or unnecessary variables from being included in the javascript bundle.